# Google Chrome bookmarks or Google Bookmarks?

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks, google-bookmarks

I'm using various Google services, one of them being Google Bookmarks.

I have a lot of bookmarks saved. They were created long time ago, when I found that it was cool to have a browser-independent service to store all my bookmarks.

But now I'm using Google Chrome as my browser and have started to use its bookmarks feature. This is a cloud service which synchronises all my bookmarks and makes them accessible every time I sign in to Chrome—so it is machine-independent. And it has folders, and tools for search and export.

Does this mean that the Google Bookmarks service has become useless? Or is there some feature of Google Bookmarks that Chrome does not provide?

Comment: What's your actual question?

Comment: Do you think that using google bookmarks webservice is redundant when you can use built-in chrome bookmarks?

Comment: Possibly. But then what about people who use multiple different browsers? Unfortunately, your question is really asking for opinions and isn't really a good fit here.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to @asif-mistry's answer, the two are different feature-wise :

- tags v folder
  Google Bookmarks use tags, meaning that a *SINGLE* bookmark can be tagged with multiple tags.
  Chrome Bookmarks uses folder, a bookmark can only exist in a single folder  when you add it to bookmark (you can copy it manually in Bookmark Manager though)
- bookmark description
  you can add description/note to Google Bookmarks but not Chrome Bookmarks
- REST API
  Google Bookmarks has an REST API (though it is [reverse](https://code.google.com/p/gmarks-android/wiki/BookmarksAPI) [engineered](http://www.mmartins.com/mmartins/googlebookmarksapi/)), so we can develop your webapp/other browser extension around it
  You can only access Chrome Bookmarks within the context of Google Chrome Browser

Answer (score 1):

Google bookmarks is a web app feature of Google which allows you to store your bookmarks on the Google server using your Gmail account.

Google Chrome Bookmarks is a Chrome feature which works in same way as bookmarks work in a major web browser.

Answer to your questions

1. No, Google bookmarks service is still useful as you can still use it.
2. Chrome bookmarks only work on one machine, If you remove Chrome all your bookmarks are gone.

You can use Google Chrome's sign in feature to synchronize your Chrome bookmarks with Google servers. You can retain all your bookmarks on your Google account this way, which means they will be available in every Chrome browser where you sign in into.

However, Google keeps those independent from Google Bookmarks.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome bookmarks has many features

(i) Chrome has feature like sign-in for browser user so if you signing in, all the bookmarks would be fetched irrespective of the machine.

(ii) You can also export the bookmark to other browser

so chrome bookmark is superior than Google bookmarks

Answer (score 1):

As a Firefox fanboy and bookmark packrat, I find browser integration for my bookmarks is a critical feature.

From the URL bar I can search bookmarks.  Or instantly create one (using the star icon).  Or re-file the current page under a different tag.

I assume Chrome appears to have feature parity with Firefox.  Barring the lack of tags.  And the obvious conclusion that they'd be just as happy if you're searching the web (which shows ads), as searching your bookmarks.

If you're happy with Chrome bookmarks & don't need support from other browsers, I suggest that's what you're going to end up using.  Import any old bookmarks you want, clear it out & don't look back.

Google have a bad reputation for killing off old features even when some people are still using them.  My presumption of Google Bookmarks is that it's not getting much love.  You'll notice "Bookmarks help" is currently going to the wrong place [questions about Google Toolbar [for IE]], and Google Bookmarks offers no option to import a bookmarks "backup file" e.g. from your browser.  Nice to see it's got a "mobile web" view [using UA-sniffing] though.